# Regular expression for pattern for [Alphanumeric]_[Alphanumeric]_[Numbers]

Tags: c#, regex

I need to identify the following pattern using regex. For e.g.

String1_String2_[Numbers]

where String1 and String2 are case insensitive and can be of any length. [Numbers] can be of any digit. I have tried google but could not find a suitable solution. 
Please suggest suitable regular expression.

Comment: try this `[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_\d+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match strings which are in this  Alphanumeric_Alphanumeric_Numbers format,

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_\d+
```

- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Matches one or more alphanumeric characters.
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b[\w-[_]]+_[\w-[_]]+_\d+\b
```

You can use character class soustraction and allow unicode char with \w